# What is wrong with this query in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a table in mysql database by running below query,

```
CREATE TABLE vms_schedule(
   schedule_id Int AUTO_INCREMENT
   ,   name varchar(255) NOT NULL
   ,   start_date timestamp NOT NULL
   ,   end_date timestamp NOT NULL
   ,   sun Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   mon Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   tue Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   wed Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   thu Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   fri Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   sat Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,PRIMARY KEY (schedule_id)
);
```

But I am getting "Invalid default value for end_date" error. Not sure what is wrong with the query as it works for start_date and not for end_date.

EDIT:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: It works here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92476

Comment: What do you mean?, you can't execute that particular `CREATE TABLE`?, it works fine in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11f07)

Comment: you can see the attachment.

Comment: Atleast wait for the response before you downvote or select to close.

Comment: If you say a column is NOT NULL, you should have to provide a default value.

Comment: @dan08 Not necessarily. Also, it shouldn't be a problem when you are creating the table

Comment: @dan08, but it works for start_date. I mean if i remove end_date column then it creates the table.

Comment: Have you checked http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date ?

Comment: Perhaps you typed a control char near `end_date` ?

Comment: Just add for example start_date timestamp NOT NULL default 0

Comment: But how come this works. CREATE TABLE vms_schedule(
   schedule_id Int AUTO_INCREMENT
   ,   name varchar(255) NOT NULL
   ,   start_date timestamp NOT NULL
   ,   sun Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   mon Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   tue Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   wed Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   thu Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   fri Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,   sat Numeric(10, 0) 
   ,PRIMARY KEY (schedule_id)
);

Comment: Perhaps you have some hidden character after `end_date`, type the query in a text file and then copy paste in `mysql`

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field   Which is the same thing that @AbhikChakraborty is pointing out above. It seems strange, but changing the `No_Zero_Date` option in my.ini may fix the behavior.

Comment: But my doubt is, it works fine if I remove the end_date column.

Comment: Which is why some people are saying that there may be some hidden character. Did you try writing that line again from scratch?

Comment: I did try. But same problem.

Comment: What if you swap start and end date in the statement. That would point out if it is the end_date line or the second timestamp column. I'm pretty sure it is a problem with having two NOT NULL timestamp columns, but can't track down anything definitive.

Comment: after swapping, it says start_date has invalid default value.

Comment: I even tried to create a table without end_date and then alter to add that column, then also it's the same :(

Comment: For funsies, can you do `start_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and if that works `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'`

Comment: Yeah, finally start_date timestamp NOT NULL
   ,   end_date timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL worked. But why it is not giving the same problem for start_date?

Comment: sql_mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: This seems close to the "multiple timestamp column" issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851672/one-mysql-table-with-multiple-timestamp-columns

Comment: @JNevill, that was my thought too, but that was changed in 5.6.5, and the OP is using 5.7

Comment: I missed where OP said which version they were on. I was going to ask earlier but I got all wrapped up in the strangeness of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this problem on MySQL 5.6.23.  I don't have MySQL 5.7.  5.7 is a development release.  You probably shouldn't be using it for production.  You probably hit a bug and you should [report it](http://bugs.mysql.com/).

I would avoid TIMESTAMP and use [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) instead.  [TIMESTAMP has many odd and confusing "features"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) and is limited to dates between 1970 and 2038.  Its simpler and more robust to use DATETIME and declare any magic you want to happen explicitly.