# MySQL - How to set to NOW() and NULL while inserting a row into a table?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO rental (rental_date, last_update, return_date)
    SET rental_date, last_update = NOW()
    AND return_date = NULL.
```

I'm trying to insert rental_date, last_update and return_date into the table rental while also setting their timestamp to NOW() and NULL.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax should be more like this.

```
INSERT INTO rental (rental_date, last_update, return_date)
SET
    rental_date = NOW()
  , last_update = NOW()
  , return_date = NULL
```

While MySQL support this `INSERT INTO ... SET` syntax it is better to use ANSI SQL Standard `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` like so

```
INSERT INTO rental
  (rental_date, last_update, return_date) 
VALUES
  (NOW(), NOW(), NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it gives me an Error 1064 on the VALUES line.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different styles of `INSERT`.

Either use the syntax

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

or use

```
INSERT INTO table SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2
```

but don't mix both.

Your values `NOW()` and `NULL` are basically correct so it's simply the way you do the insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/4852095/1712016

You can update rental_date and last_update field with null value or you can query like this.

```
INSERT INTO rental (rental_date, last_update, return_date)
VALUES(NOW(),NOW(),NULL)

or

INSERT INTO rental (rental_date, last_update, return_date)
VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to SELECT now(), you can't use a values clause:

```
INSERT INTO rental
  (rental_date, last_update, return_date) 
SELECT NOW(), NOW(), NULL;
```