# MySQL: Multiple Timestamps in One Table for DateAdded, DateUpdated

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-timestamp

I want to have multiple Timestamps in one table for columns `DateAdded` and `DateUpdated`. I have this incorrect definition where `DateAdded` is at `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` and only works for `DateUpdated`.

```
`DateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`DateUpdated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I try to edit to have 2 Timestamps I get this error:

```
 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

Please help me with correct workaround. I can see the issue is known but I am not seeing a solution anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851672/one-mysql-table-with-multiple-timestamp-columns
You can refer below link too.
http://jasonbos.co/two-timestamp-columns-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace invalid timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE tab MODIFY `DateAdded` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
                                                     -- or any other valid value
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a064c56f503a69d189c136677868ff7)**